# How to slice time series data by values of 0 in python?

Tags: python, time, series

I am trying to take my time series data and divide it by points where the y-axis is 0, so parsing the data between intervals of 0 on the y-axis. This might be called "slicing", but I am not sure. I am working in python. I am doing this because I want to distinguish separate "events" in the data (event referring to any action happening in the data, for whichever context). I want to delineate where an event starts and stops, and this is why I am parsing by 0s.

This would create a separate time series set for each new interval, as such:

0,(values above 0),0,(values above 0),0,(values above 0),0... and so on.

Now for each of these separate time series sets (representing an event), I want to calculate the area under the curve and identify those intervals with the largest area under the curve. Finally, I want to output the range, such that the output would tell me the greatest area was found between 3/4/20 and 2/25/20.

Is this doable in python? Can you really parse a time series set like I described? I unfortunately do not have any code yet, since I am first still trying to conceptualize this and find out which functions I would actually need.

I have this provided sample time series data I am looking at (showing daily values throughout a given year):

```
np.random.seed(1)
N = 365
rng = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', periods=N)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(20, size=(365, 1)), 
                  columns=['value'], 
                  index=rng)
df.head()
```

Comment: Can you add some sample data to get more clear insight

Comment: Also, provide a code snippet of what you have tried so far and include a sample data set to run it against.

Comment: I have updated my post to include a sample time series data set I am working with, showing a different value for each day in a year. Unfortunately I am so lost in how to go about approaching this challenge that I unfortunately do not have any code to begin with.